# What is $(d\circ \iota_X) (fdx\wedge dy)(P,Q)$ equal to?

Tags: differential-forms

I am trying to calculate $(d\circ \iota_X) (fdx\wedge dy)(P,Q)$. Here $fdx\wedge dy$ is clearly a 2-form, and P,Q are vectors.

Is $(d\circ \iota_X) (fdx\wedge dy)(P,Q)$ simply equal to $df\wedge dx\wedge dy (X,P,Q)$? Or am I missing a step?

Comment: What you wrote is $(\iota_X\circ d)(fdx\wedge dy)(P, Q)$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese- How does one calculate $d\circ \iota_X$ here then? What is the procedure?

Comment: First use $\iota_X(fdx\wedge dy) = f(\iota_X dx) dy - f (\iota_X dy) dx$.

Comment: What you wrote down is $\iota_X\big(d(f\,dx\wedge dy)\big)(P,Q)$.